# Failed to install expo package with error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1 yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

Im currently trying to update my Expo SDK from 36.0.0 to atleast 37.0.0 with the command `expo update`
however im getting the error:

```
  × Failed to install expo package with error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:288:31)
    at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:241:16)
    at upgradeAsync (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\upgrade.ts:465:5)
    at C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\upgrade.ts:701:7
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:302:7)
```

npm version : 6.14.8
yarn version : 2.2.2 i also tried it with a lower version 1.x.x
expo diagnostics :

```
 Expo CLI 3.27.4 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.18.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 2.2.2 - C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.14.8 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^36.0.0 => 36.0.2
      react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
      react-dom: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
      react-native-web: ^0.11.7 => 0.11.7
      react-navigation: 3.11.1 => 3.11.1
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Hopefully someone can help me, any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

remove this line from package.json

`"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz"`

now remove node_modules

now:

`yarn install`

now add that line back in package.json

again

`yarn install`

now if it succeeds, do a

`expo upgrade`

I solved after 2 days

Answer (score 52):

This is one way how I solved this issue.

I deleted the `yarn.lock` file & `.expo` folder and tried running `expo upgrade` and it worked.

I was upgrading from SDK 44 to SDK 45.

Comment: This helped me when upgrading from expo 44 to 46

Comment: This helped me when upgrading from expo 44 to 45. Also, I need to run yarn upgrade to upgrade the old packages.

Comment: Getting the same error as OP after these steps. Also going from 44 to 45, using `expo upgrade 45`

Comment: Use the local cli or try to upgrade the `expo-cli` to the latest and then try upgrading

Answer (score 7):

I ran `yarn install` (`npm install` should do the same thing.) in my project folder first. Then `expo upgrade` command worked.

Answer (score 4):

By any chance is this a monorepo? I ran into this error because I accidentally upgrade expo in the root folder

Comment: unfortunatly it isnt.

Comment: I experience this issue with a monorepo

Comment: To solve it in a monorepo, I first ran `yarn install` in the root

Comment: Where should we run the `expo upgrade` if we are working with yarn monorepos?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way how I solved this issue.

I deleted the yarn.lock file & .expo folder and tried running expo upgrade and it worked.

I was upgrading from SDK 44 to SDK 45.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the **yarn.lock** file and tried running **expo upgrade** and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, this error occurred because I had a package that didn't exist in my package.json. In fact, I must have made a mistake and I had this line:     `"package_name": "^1.0.2"` in my package.json file;)

Answer (score 1):

For expo version 50, my issue was that my node was version 16 while node 18 is required.

Comment: i still had to delete the folders yarn.lock and .expo and then upgrade node: `sudo npm install n -g` and `sudo n stable`

Comment: @DanielCettour Interesting, for me it worked as soon as I switched node versions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `yarn install` (`npm install` should do the same thing.) in my project folder first. Then `expo upgrade` command worked.

Answer (score 0):

just install expo-notifications using normal package installation as below
instead of `expo install expo-notifications` use

npm i expo-notifications

Answer (score 0):

I was running expo upgrade from root directory of my app and experienced the same error
I changed to the directory of my mobile app and it ran successfully without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I did is to delete the yarn.lock
then run the upgrade command, the non-zero error goes away

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re using an old version of npm. Try upgrading. Also make sure you’re using a recent even-numbered version of node (e.g. version 16 or 18)

If that doesn’t fix it, you can try running the following:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

You can set it back to the default `false` again afterwards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the **same issue** when trying to run :

```
npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject
```

**The cause of the problem:** dependency issue between the packages coming from **react-native package** , so if u try to remove react-native from package.json then -> `npm install` **no errors** will appear.

**The solution:**

- Go to package.json
- Change the react-native version // mine was 17.1 I changed it to 17.0
- Remove node modules
- Run : `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

And now it should be **solved** ! CHEERS !

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on expo react native, the latest version.

This worked for me:

- Deleting .expo
- Deleting node_modules
- `npm install`
- `expo upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

None of the provided answers worked for me, but

```
npm cache clean --force
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it, just remove the package-lock.json and run the command again eas build -p android --profile preview