# Error: Failed to install expo package with error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1 yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1

Tags: sdk, expo, yarnpkg, updates

I've been trying to upgrade the SDK for expo from version 40.0.1 to 44.0.0. However, i'm still getting this error

> ✖ Failed to install expo package with error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
> yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
> Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
> at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:476:26)
> at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
> at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
> at Socket. (node:internal/child_process:453:11)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
> at Pipe. (node:net:665:12)
> ...
> at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
> at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:327:31)
> at YarnPackageManager.addWithParametersAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:272:16)
> at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:276:5)
> at upgradeAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:496:7)
> at actionAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:42:3)

I've tried every suggestion from similar issues on this site, but I've had no help. Does anyone have any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332470/5516544

Try deleting yarn.lock file & .expo folder and try running expo upgrade again.

It worked for me upgrading expo from 44 -> 45